# Deleting 32 registry key from a 64 application

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, registry

I'm trying to write a generic API to deal with windows registry.
of course, the first problems that come to mind is all the cross 32-64 excessing plus the problems the UAC poses since win 7..

in my API , I can create new subkeys from 64 application to the 32-registry keys , but when I try to delete them,
I face several problems.

for example, my "create or return a subkey if exists" function looks like this:

```
Registry::SubKey Registry::RegistryKey::subKey(const std::wstring& subkey){
    HKEY registryKey;
    auto result = RegCreateKeyEx(m_RegistryKey, subkey.c_str(), 0, //m_RegistryKey is 100% valid , for example HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
        NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE ,KEY_ALL_ACCESS | ((Registry::currentBitMode() == 64) ? KEY_WOW64_64KEY : KEY_WOW64_32KEY), 
            NULL, &registryKey, NULL); //currentBitMode return 64 or 32 , depends on what the developer set beforehand
    return Registry::SubKey(registryKey, false);
}
```

and it works perfectly. I can create new subkeys under the 32-subset of the registry or the 64.

now, here is my deleting methode:

```
bool Registry::RegistryKey::deleteSubKey(const std::wstring& subkey){
    std::wstring name(MAX_PATH, 0);
    HKEY subKeyHandle;

auto buffer = subkey;
//m_RegistryKey - member variable, should be valid. at least it's valid when I try it
auto isFunctionSuccessful = RegOpenKeyEx(m_RegistryKey, buffer.c_str(), 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS | (Registry::currentBitMode() == 64) ? KEY_WOW64_64KEY : KEY_WOW64_32KEY, &subKeyHandle);

if (isFunctionSuccessful != ERROR_SUCCESS){
    std::cout << "error : " << isFunctionSuccessful << "\n";
    return false;
}

if (buffer.back() != L'\\'){
    buffer += L'\\';
}

DWORD dwSize = MAX_PATH;
isFunctionSuccessful = RegEnumKeyEx(subKeyHandle, 0, &name[0], &dwSize, NULL, NULL, NULL, nullptr);

if (isFunctionSuccessful == ERROR_SUCCESS){
    do {
        name = name.substr(0, name.find(wchar_t(0)));
        if (!deleteSubKey(buffer + name)) {
            break;
        }

        dwSize = MAX_PATH;
        name.resize(MAX_PATH);
        isFunctionSuccessful = RegEnumKeyEx(subKeyHandle, 0, &name[0], &dwSize, NULL, NULL, NULL, nullptr);
    } while (isFunctionSuccessful == ERROR_SUCCESS);
}

RegCloseKey(subKeyHandle);

isFunctionSuccessful = RegDeleteKeyEx(m_RegistryKey, subkey.c_str(), (Registry::currentBitMode() == 64) ? KEY_WOW64_64KEY : KEY_WOW64_32KEY, 0);

if (isFunctionSuccessful == ERROR_SUCCESS){
    return true;
}

return false;
```

}

this is my C++ variation on the (nasty) MSDN example here :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724235%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

now , here is the problem :
I , for example, create a new 32 key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/Software in the name of XXX ,
I can open it with my function , see it's values and see it under regedit.

if I try to delete under the string "Software\XXX" I get error code 2 - File note found.
If I try to delete it inder the stirng  SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\XXX I get error code 5 - Access denied.
even when running the executable as admin , I still see the 2 error code . any Ideas?

Comment: Is your process virtualized?

Comment: undet task manager - > processes -> UAC virtualization : not allowed.

Comment: Use the KEY_WOW64_64KEY to access the 64-bit registry view from a 32-bit program, KEY_WOW64_32KEY to see the 32-bit registry view from a 64-bit program.  Deleting keys you don't have sufficient permission to delete is a non-starter of course.   You must ask for UAC elevation with a manifest.  Or the access permissions of the (parent) key need to be changed so a non-privileged user account can whack it.

Comment: @HansPassant can I do it programatically from within the application without a manifest?

Comment: Guessing at what "it" might mean: asking for UAC elevation requires a manifest, no other way.

Comment: @HansPassant The code already uses the alternate registry view flags. And it has a manifest because it is not virtualised.

Comment: @HansPassant: "*asking for UAC elevation requires a manifest, no other way*" - that is not entirely true. Using `ShellExecute/Ex()` with the "runas" verb, or the COM Elevation Moniker, will invoke UAC elevation without needing a manifest on the target process/object.

Comment: @DavidHaim: you should use `RegDeleteTree()` or `SHDeleteKey()` to delete a key and its subkeys, instead of enumerating the subkeys manually to delete them. The `RegDeleteKeyEx()` documentation even says as much.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `RegDeleteKeyEx` is the only function that can delete keys from 64 bit app from 32 registry and vice versa

Comment: @DavidHaim: Not true. Use `RegOpenKeyEx()` to open a parent 32/64bit key and then use `RegDeleteTree()`/`SHDeleteKey()` to recursively delete its subkeys as needed.